# React-tools JSX compile nested folder error

Tags: facebook, build, npm, reactjs

I'm trying to use the Node module react-tools provided by Facebook to compile my JSX files into their appropriate .js files.

```
jsx --extension jsx --no-cache-dir js/src js/build
```

However, using the supported command I'm not able to build files which are nested inside sub folders in my `src` folder.

I have `js/src/module1/main.jsx`
If I build this now, react-tools successfully builds

```
module("module1/main")
```

but then spews an error:

```
no such file of directory js/build/module1/main
```

However, if I make the directory `js/build/module1` first, then I don't see any problems. It seems like react expects the output directory to already have the sub-directories in it. Am I doing something wrong here or is this a bug with react-tools at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally a bug in the main dependency of the jsx tool. :(

I filed https://github.com/reactjs/commoner/issues/67 to track.

Comment: And the fix is in master, so we'll pick it up with the next release!

Comment: Thanks, can we get an update on when we can expect the next release. Thanks for the quickness :D